# Error passing a lambda function as 3rd argument to QObject::connect

Tags: c++, qt, lambda, qobject, qcustomplot

I'm trying to call `QObject::connect` by passing a lambda function as the 3rd parameter.

However, I Visual Visual Studio gives me the following error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x0000000066B48265 (Qt5Cored.dll) in
>   QCustomPlotInVS_FirstTry.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading
>   location 0x0000000000000008.

Here is the top 3 lines on the Call Stack when the error occurs:

> Qt5Cored.dll!QListData::size()                                 Line 91
>    QCustomPlotInVS_FirstTry.exe!QList::size() Line 132     QCustomPlotInVS_FirstTry.exe!QCustomPlot::graph(int index)     Line 9657

Line 91 in qList.h is:
`inline int size() const { return d->end - d->begin; }`

I think I'm getting this error because I'm incorrectly trying to use a pointer (i.e. the  `QCustomPlot* plot`) with a lambda function.

Is my syntax for the lambda function correct?
If not, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the function in which I call the `QObject::connect` with a lambda function:

```
void setupRealTimePlot(QCustomPlot* plot, QTimer* dataTimer)
{
    plot->addGraph(); // blue line
    plot->graph(0)->setPen(QPen(Qt::blue));
    plot->graph(0)->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(240, 255, 200)));
    plot->graph(0)->setAntialiasedFill(false);
    plot->addGraph(); // red line
    plot->graph(1)->setPen(QPen(Qt::red));
    plot->graph(0)->setChannelFillGraph(plot->graph(1));

    plot->addGraph(); // blue dot
    plot->graph(2)->setPen(QPen(Qt::blue));
    plot->graph(2)->setLineStyle(QCPGraph::lsNone);
    plot->graph(2)->setScatterStyle(QCPScatterStyle::ssDisc);
    plot->addGraph(); // red dot
    plot->graph(3)->setPen(QPen(Qt::red));
    plot->graph(3)->setLineStyle(QCPGraph::lsNone);
    plot->graph(3)->setScatterStyle(QCPScatterStyle::ssDisc);

    plot->xAxis->setTickLabelType(QCPAxis::ltDateTime);
    plot->xAxis->setDateTimeFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    plot->xAxis->setAutoTickStep(false);
    plot->xAxis->setTickStep(2);
    plot->axisRect()->setupFullAxesBox();

    // make left and bottom axes transfer their ranges to right and top axes:
    QObject::connect(plot->xAxis, SIGNAL(rangeChanged(QCPRange)), plot->xAxis2, SLOT(setRange(QCPRange)));
    QObject::connect(plot->yAxis, SIGNAL(rangeChanged(QCPRange)), plot->yAxis2, SLOT(setRange(QCPRange)));

    // setup a timer that repeatedly calls MainWindow::realtimeDataSlot:
    QObject::connect(dataTimer, &QTimer::timeout, 
        [&]()
        {
            // calculate two new data points:
            double key = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toMSecsSinceEpoch()/1000.0;
            static double lastPointKey = 0;
            if (key-lastPointKey > 0.01) // at most add point every 10 ms
            {
            double value0 = qSin(key); //qSin(key*1.6+qCos(key*1.7)*2)*10 + qSin(key*1.2+0.56)*20 + 26;
            double value1 = qCos(key); //qSin(key*1.3+qCos(key*1.2)*1.2)*7 + qSin(key*0.9+0.26)*24 + 26;
            // add data to lines:
            plot->graph(0)->addData(key, value0);
            plot->graph(1)->addData(key, value1);
            // set data of dots:
            plot->graph(2)->clearData();
            plot->graph(2)->addData(key, value0);
            plot->graph(3)->clearData();
            plot->graph(3)->addData(key, value1);
            // remove data of lines that's outside visible range:
            plot->graph(0)->removeDataBefore(key-8);
            plot->graph(1)->removeDataBefore(key-8);
            // rescale value (vertical) axis to fit the current data:
            plot->graph(0)->rescaleValueAxis();
            plot->graph(1)->rescaleValueAxis(true);
            lastPointKey = key;
            }
            // make key axis range scroll with the data (at a constant range size of 8):
            plot->xAxis->setRange(key+0.25, 8, Qt::AlignRight);
            plot->replot();

            // calculate frames per second:
            static double lastFpsKey;
            static int frameCount;
            ++frameCount;
            if (key-lastFpsKey > 2) // average fps over 2 seconds
            {
            lastFpsKey = key;
            frameCount = 0;
            }
        });

    dataTimer->start(0); // Interval 0 means to refresh as fast as possible

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are capturing stack-allocated variables by reference (first offender: `plot`) in a closure that is going to be called later; all that stuff is going to be garbage once your closure is called. Capture by value instead.

Comment: You're answer is correct.  I changed the `[&](){//...}` to `[=](){//...}` and it worked.  However, it's not clear to me why.  I thought if I captured by value it would create a copy of the variable(s) (in my case `QCustomPlot* plot`), then any changes to the copy would not apply to the original variable.  I think I just realized that my concern is wrong because copying a pointer will give a new variable that still points to the object I want to modify.  Does my interpretation seem correct?

Comment: Exactly. You may get it more easily resolving the references as pointers: capturing a local pointer variable by reference is like storing a pointer to it inside a double pointer. When later you try to use it, it is pointing to a local variable that no longer exist. Capturing it by value, instead, is like creating a new `QCustomPlot *` which point to the original object (the value of the pointer is the address of the pointed object).